# How to use gddrescue to make an ISO from hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to run `ddrescue` to make an ISO of an old crashed drive. I just don't know how to find the name of the drive to specify when telling `ddrescue` to run.

If someone could please just tell me how to find this out so I could get this started.

Comment: I doubt `ddrescue` can make an ISO from a *hard drive* source...

Answer (score 1):

There are two valuable commands to find out what drives we have attached:

- List drives attached:

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```
- List partitions:

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l
  ```

With these commands you should have all information you need to run [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html). In case the drive is not listed it is not detected from BIOS either due to a lethal hardware defect or broken cables.